# Renaming virtual directory in IIS 5.1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, web-hosting

I have taken a Branch of a Project from TFS. Another branch is already in my computer.

The projects contains a virtual directory which is hosted in my system's IIS (5.1) and takes path from there

After getting all files to my computer , VS 2008 says that the Virtual Directory already exists in the IIS and do I want to overwrite it?

When I select No it creates another Virtual Directory with the same name but with suffix _1

I don't like this name and I want to rename the suffix with _Branch_1

I tried by going to inetmgr and renaming the Virtual Directory -> Application Name in properties of VD.

But it does not take effect , I also saw it after browsing a test aspx file from the site , URL still shows _1 suffix.

Every time I rename the Application Name and open Visual Studio , it shows same message and adds new suffix e.g. _2  next time _3 and goes on.

Any idea how to rename it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Solution file in your project. What the virtual direcotry has defined, open it in notepad and check.
To rename the Virutal direcotry, stop the app pool associated with the application and then you can rename it.

hope it may help you.